# Binding an SSL cert to specific endpoint in an Azure hosted API

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have an App Service with a GoDaddy SSL certificate bound so I can access the website using https without getting any errors. On top of the App Service I have an API Management (APIM) service with endpoints that can be called to retrieve information from our system. For one of our vendors we need to create an endpoint and bind their self signed certificate on the endpoint.

What's the best way to do this? I wasn't able to add it in APIM's proxy URL, the default SSL certificate for the AppService is being loaded. I wanted to create an Azure Function and bind the SSL certificate to the proxy url and than pass the request to the backend but don't see where I can add an SSL cert. I looked online and I couldn't really find a solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to use certificate to authenticate to backend service? To setup a custom hostname at APIM for your clients? Or to authenticate a client making a call to APIM?

Answer (score 1):

This is doable according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain#how-apim-proxy-server-responds-with-ssl-certificates-in-the-tls-handshake). [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients) is the article talking about it.

Sample policy snippet to check cert against thumbprint:

```
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint != "desired-thumbprint")" >
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
        </return-response>
    </when>
</choose>
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain#use-the-azure-portal-to-set-a-custom-domain-name) is how you add custom domain.